# How force download an .xlsx file in PHP without having it corrupted?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

None of the already existing questions have helped me.
I'm trying to force download an excel file with the file type `.xlsx`. It works perfectly fine in a download code like this:

`echo "<a href='" . $dateiname . "'>Datei herunterladen</a>";`

But whenever I try to make a forced download, it doesn't work. I've tried various headers from various questions on stackoverflow, the last two being

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $dateiname . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dateiname));
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

and

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($dateiname));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dateiname));
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I tried both in the same file as where I create the file, but also in a separate file, but either way I always get the error:

> Excel cannot open the file (filename) because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corruted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

The file itself on my server seems perfectly fine.

Comment: not sure I've ever seen it do that .. try phpspreadsheet ^^ tis a great lib for this kinda thing that works 10/10

Comment: @treyBake I can't sadly, I'm using PHPExcel which is incredibly outdated, but currently don't have any other choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found how I used PHPExcel to force downloading an `xls`file.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}.{$fileFormat}");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Hope it helps.